# MYSQL Connection: Access Denied

Tags: java, netbeans, workbench

These are my codes for the database connection:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.44.222.111/try?" 
+ "user=jenny&password=perez");
```

After running the program, it display this **error**:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
Access denied for user 'jenny' @ '%' to database 'try'
```

I am using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: What about port number `3306`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to MySQL Workbench, then User Privileges, click your username, then check all Administrative Roles then click apply. This will allow connection for user 'jenny'.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, user 'jenny' does not have access to connect to database from any host(%). On mysql prompt, run  the following command to provide privileges to user 'jenny' to connect from any host.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON try.* TO 'jenny'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

You may use specific PRIVILEGES instead of ALL as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This would indicate that your user does not have permission to access that database from any client host ('%').

MySQL uses a four part mechanism for allowing access:

- username
- password
- database
- client host

You need to make sure that the user is authorised in MySql to access the 'try' database and is allowed to connect from any client host ('%') and has the correct username and password.

Also, you should ensure you are connecting to port 3306 (unless MySQL is running on a non-standard port).